# Android: Can I lower the latency of onTouch?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, low-latency

I'm working on an app that requires high accuracy touch handling. I want my OnTouchListener to receive as many onTouch events as possible so I can see exactly where their finger went. Is there some way to crank up the frequency at which I receive these events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an explicit way to do so. As for an implicit way, read http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/39eea4d7f6e6dfca

The most important part of that link is "the system delivers events as fast as you will process them". So, if you want to maximize touch event delivery, use threading in a way that the UI thread has enough time to constantly process touch events.